# Cannot access 'response' before initialization trying to pass value from one post request to another in Express

Tags: javascript, api, express, post, initialization

So I have two post methods in my express app and I am using an API SDK for these functions.

So the first post request runs and generates a random ID value. Then my 2nd post request I have to manually copy the ID from the console, then add it after the `.deliveryQuoteAccept` code

```
app.post("/get-quote", async (req, res) => {
  const response = await client.deliveryQuote({
    external_delivery_id: uuidv4(), //This creates unique ID value
  });

  res.send(response);
  console.log("HERE IS THE ID", response.data.external_delivery_id)

)};


app.post("/accept-quote", async (req, res) => {
  const response = await client.deliveryQuoteAccept(
    "55acc96a-e5f2-45a6-8fce-cf62836244a0" //Manually typed the ID value here
  );

  res.send(response)
  console.log(response.data.external_delivery_id) //This logs the ID from the get-quote post request
```

So the code above works perfectly fine.
**My problem is I have to manually copy and paste that long ID value each time I create an order.**

How do I add that value inside of my 2nd post request so that it will get the value each time automatically?

If I try to do this, it will say `Cannot access 'response' before initialization`

```
app.post("/accept-quote", async (req, res) => {
      const response = await client.deliveryQuoteAccept(
        response.data.external_delivery_id
      );  //This causes an error, can't access response before initialization 
    
      res.send(response)
      console.log(response.data.external_delivery_id)
```

However, it will log the ID by logging the value outside of the parentheses. It won't work when I put the same code inside of the parentheses of the `.deliveryQuoteAccept()` code?

Any way to pass a value from one post request to another dynamically?

Comment: Your indentation is unclear. Is the second `app.post()` call in the response handler of the first? If so then use different names or remove replace the first `const` with `let` and get rid of the second `const`

Comment: At a high level, are you trying to store some value server-side between requests?  If so then you'd need to persist it somewhere, such as in session storage or a database.  For this particular value, is it unreasonable to expect the client code to retain the value from the first response and use it in subsequent requests?  That's a very, *very* common pattern, on which much of web development is built.

Comment: oh they're two different request and separate

Comment: @david I updated the code, but it's two post request, I just forget to add the closing })